# How to improve memory usage when generating a contiguous permutation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have code that needs to generate a contiguous permutation:

```
(1..n).flat_map {|x| array.map {|y| (x..y) unless x > y } }.compact
```

Which outputs:

```
[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2], [2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], 
[3], [3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4], [4, 5], [5]]
```

It works really well with low sizes of `n`, but when I have `n = 100000` I run out of memory.  Is there a way to improve this but keeping them contiguous?

I need to perform a `reject!` iterating over `poisonous` and `allergic` arrays:

```
array = (1..n)
permutations = array.flat_map {|x| array.map {|y| (x..y) unless x > y } }.compact

poisonous.each_with_index do |x, i|
  permutations.reject! { |y| y.include?(x) && y.include?(allergic[i]) }
end
```

The problem:

```
poisonous = [3,4,6]
allergic = [5,6,7]
```

These numbers can't be together:

```
 3 -> 4
 4 -> 6
 6 -> 7

 combinations = [[1], [3,4], [4,5]]
```

So, `[3,4]` is not a valid combination.

Comment: I showed the output just so other can see the result I need, but I'm generating an array of enumerators because I'm not doing (x..y).to_a, but even though I'm running out of memory. How could I use even less memory? PS: I will need the entire permutation array for later processing.

Comment: It appears you wish to produce an array which, if flattened, would contain `n*(1+n)/2 + (n-1)*n/2 + ... + 1` elements. That is on the order of `n**3` elements (but there probably is a closed-form expression to compute that number that could be derived fairly easily). In any event, it’s no surprise that you will have memory problems if you want to hold that array in memory when `n = 10**5`, regardless of how you compute it.

Comment: Even if you derived an enumerator to generate those arrays, or created a method `m` such that `m(i)` returned the ith array, you are still generating `n*(1+n)/2` arrays upon which you are performing some operations. If `n = 10**5` that’s a pretty big number, on the order of `10**10`. If you edit your question to explains why you want to generate all those arrays we may be able to be more helpful.

Comment: I edited the post to show the complete code. Thanks!

Comment: Using the bang versions of operators can help with memory as it means the action occurs on the current object rather than a duplicate. So use `map!` and `compact!`.

Comment: @ReggieB that is correct, but even not duplicating the object the base array is taking up to 800 mb of allocated memory after the permutations are generated.

Comment: You did not post anything reproducible, but I believe all you need is to make an enumerator lazy. It would slow down the computations a bit, but will run in `O(1)` of memory.

Comment: This is really frustrating! You seem to want to create an array that contains ordered subsets of `arr = (1..n).to_a` that are not poisonous and/or allergic, but you have it in your head that you must first create a certain array of subsets of `arr` that have nothing to do with being poisonous and/or allergic and then remove certain arrays. That may not be the only or best way of doing it, however. That's often called an [X-Y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Please define the arrays  `poisonous` and `allergic` (what is `poisonous[i]` and `allergic[i]`?).

Comment: ...Also, do you want to exclude arrays that are *either* poisonous or allergic or arrays that are *both* poisonous and allergic? You revised question suggests it is the latter, which seems odd. One other thing: why do you care about the order of the elements in the array you wish to construct?

Comment: The poisonous and allergic are arrays with random numbers lower than n. The order must be preserved, it is required from the problem im solving, not from the permutations array, but the numbers inside each permutation, they need to be contiguous. I was creating they array first because I need to have the combinations in hand so I can reject some of them, but I improved it a lot, checkout my answer below. The only thing now is that I still can't make it work for large N like 100000 or even 5000.

Comment: Please also answer the first question in my last comment. When replying to comments asking for clarification it is best to edit your question rather than elaborating in comments as not all readers read all comments. You forgot to include my username in your comment so SO did not inform me that a comment had been left for me. I know you understand that but be more vigilant in including usernames in comments, else they may never be read by the person to whom they are directed.

Comment: @CarySwoveland a permutation array can't contain a number that is poisonous to another number that is in the allergic array and is also inside the permutation array, so the final permutation can't have both numbers. it's a bit confusing but that's it. And at the end I need the number of all clean combinations, without any poisonous or allergic numbers.

Comment: "...a number that is poisonous to another number that is allergic..." doesn't make sense. Numbers are neither poisonous nor allergic. Work harder at your explanation! If you with to compute only the number of "clean combinations" I don't understand why the order in which you process the combinations is important. Again, please edit your question. We're getting close and it seems to be an interesting question, so keep at it. One last thing: asking a clear, complete and precise question is an essential skill in coding, for the same is required when writing specs for code.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I added more details to the question.

Comment: So the arrays `poisonous` and `allergic` are always the same size? And, again, if you wish to compute only the number of "clean combinations" why is the order in which you process the combinations important?

Comment: Here is an example of how you might state your question (if my understanding is correct): 'I am given `n` components. Some pairs are "dangerous". I wish to compute the total number of combinations of subsets of these `n` compounds such that no subset contains any dangerous pairs of elements. The subsets range in size from `1` to `n`. The subsets are not ordered.'

Comment: See "[What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/153968)"

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the memory issue by using less variables as possible and doing calculations directly while generating the permutation, although processing time has increased a bit, it is using a lot less memory (dropped from 800mb to 32mb approximately). I'm open for suggestions to improve it even more.

```
counter = 0
(1..n).each {|x|
  (1..n).each {|y|
    counter += 1 if !(x > y) && !poisonous.each_with_index.select {|poison, i|  (x..y).include?(poison) && (x..y).include?(allergic[i])}.any?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following computes the number of "clean combinations". As no large arrays are produced it has modest memory requirements.

```
require 'set'

def clean_combos(n, poisonous, allergic)
  arr = (1..n).to_a
  bad_allergies = poisonous.zip(allergic).to_h
  arr.sum do |m|
    arr.combination(m).sum do |combo|
      combo_set = combo.to_set
      bad_allergies.any? do |poison, allergy|
        combo_set.include?(poison) && combo_set.include?(allergy)
      end ? 0 : 1
    end
  end
end
```

```
n = 10
poisonous = [3,4,6]
allergic = [5,6,7]
```

```
clean_combos(n, poisonous, allergic)
  #=> 479
```

`bad_allergies` is found to equal `{3=>5, 4=>6, 6=>7}`.

This concludes that, for the array `[1, 2,..., 10]`, there are 479 combinations of elements of size between `1` and `10` such that, for each combination, `3` and `5` are not both included, and neither are `4` and `5`, and `6` and `7`.

See [Array#zip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-zip), [Array#to_h](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-to_h), [Array#sum](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-sum), [Array#combination](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-combination), [Hash#any?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-any-3F) and [Set#include?](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-include-3F). `Array#to_set` is added when `include 'set'` is executed.

I've converted each `combo` to a set to speed lookups.

Some tweaks might improve efficiency, so experimentation may be called for. This may depend on the size of the array `poisonous` (and of `allergic`) relative to `n`.

Comment: Please let me know if my understanding of the question is incorrect.